# How to get info about viewport size, screen resolution, OS, etc. using CPA in a packaged app?

Tags: google-analytics, google-chrome-app

I'm integrating analytics to my app using the CPA library and so far I'm only able to record "appView" when the app gets launched, which is great.

I can't see any reference to it in the [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-platform-analytics/wiki) but if you search "viewport" or "resolution" in the "google-analytics-bundle.js" you actually find something, so I figured there must be a way. I tried `tracker.sendviewportSize();` but it didn't work, that would've been too easy.

**EDIT**: I feel like a fool, the OS and the screen resolution are under the audience report in google analytics. I should have fiddled with it a little more before asking. I still would like to know about the viewport though.

Also, is it ok if a create a property for testing purposes? I understand I can't delete properties and there's a limit of 20. So, would it be ok to have one to test if the tracking code is reporting correctly?

**EDIT2**: I created an event for it:

`var vpS = document.documentElement.clientWidth + "x" + document.documentElement.clientHeight;
tracker.sendEvent("Viewport", "Size", vpS);`

Seems to do the trick.